# C# wrap text inside a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to display a list of words in a listbox, wrapped them together. Below is an example what I want to do. I was able to add words to listbox with a comma and in one line. Can you please help me to wrap this text.

For comma separation I used,
ListBox.Items.Add(string.Join(",", myList));

Expected output-
[image]

Below is my output[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think its possible to print **`multiple`** text lines per ListBox item with the standard **`ListBox`**. Try using a  **`TextBox`** instead, with **`Multiline = true`**

```
  this.textBox1.Text = string.Join(",", UniqueWord(myList));
```